# Add Map to Master detail Page returns Exception

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i am using xamarin forms(PCL) and execute the App using Windows phone emulator
i created a master detail page

```
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <ContentPage Title="Menu">
      <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <Button Text="buttonOne"/>
        <Button Text="ButtonTwo"/>
        <Button Text="ButtonThree"/>
      </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
  </MasterDetailPage.Master>

  <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
      <x:Arguments>
          <local:MasterPage />
      </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
  </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

the details page is

```
<StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Hello World"/>
        <StackLayout>
            <maps:Map  WidthRequest="320" HeightRequest="200" />
        </StackLayout>
 </StackLayout>
```

it stops at

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
            UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) 
                 global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            };
#endif
```

and return this exception( Native View = Unable to evaluate the expression. Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x80070057.)

Note:

1. if i remove the WidthRequest and HeightRequest of the map it works
   but the map would not appear.
2. **And this Exception Takes place only when navigate to the master
   detail page.**

Comment: Are you following this tutorial by any chance? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/

Comment: @nkorai yes and the details page that contains the map works perfectly and display map when i set it as root page.

Comment: @nkorai and i have discovered that when i set the master Details page itself as a root page this exception won't take place, it place only when i navigate from any page to the master detail page .

Comment: Can you navigate from some page to the Master Detail page successfully when you do not have the Map in the the Master Detail page?

Comment: @nkorai yes without the map it Navigate successfully , another wired thing happened i was navigating to the page using Navigation.Pushasync() but when i tried Navigation.Pushmodalasync() it resolved the issue and i have no reason why that happened and why pushModalAsync() resolved it , i wish if you can explain it to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this resolves to not being a problem with the Maps part specifically but an issue with Navigating to Master Detail pages, since PushModalAsync(...) puts the Master Detail Page on top of a *new* Navigation stack instead of pushing it onto the top of the *current* Navigation stack which is what PushAsync(...) does.

Here's a link to a Xamarin Forms Forum question that appears to have the same problem:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21461/navigation-pushasync-not-working

Apparently MasterDetail pages do not like being navigated to, and both Android and iOS prefer to have it as the root page. That isn't to say this is impossible to do, I believe it just has to be done a little differently. Some dependecy injection/custom rendering might help here.

I found this Xamarin Forms article very useful when learning about Navigation, might help you out as well:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical/

Comment: IMHO, this is on the list of things to address before Xamarin forms can be considered "fully baked" - great framework, just requires a little hack-ery from time-to-time